# How to get response time in sec in aggregate report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

[How to get response time in sec in the aggregate report in JMeter  currently its MS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQukb.png)

Avg - an Arithmetic mean for all responses (sum of all times / count)
Minimal response time (ms) need in Sec
Maximum response time (ms) need in Sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) it is not possible.

As a workaround you can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and divide Connect Time, Latency and Elapsed Time by 1000, this way you will have these metrics in seconds.

Example code:

```
prev.setConnectTime((prev.getConnectTime() / 1000) as long)
prev.setLatency((prev.getLatency() / 1000) as long)
org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.writeField(prev, 'elapsedTime', (prev.getTime() / 1000) as long, true)
```

Be aware that you will loose precision, i.e. of you had 400 ms response time - you will get it as 0, for 600 ms response time it will be 1 second, etc.

More information:

- [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html)
- [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)